# Virtual attribute not holding value when calling via join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attributes

Maybe rookie problem, maybe not, maybe i am lack of OOT but I still can't answer why I cant get the the value of instance variable @upgrade which was assigned to true.

```
class OrderTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    attr_writer :upgrade #to hold upgrade process across actions

    def upgrade
        @upgrade || false
    end

    def from_time
        p self.inspect
        ------------------------> they looks same
        p self.upgrade
        ------------------------> is true as is supposed to be

        p self.user.order_template.inspect
        ------------------------> they looks same
        p self.user.order_template.upgrade
        ------------------------> is false but i am expecting true

        self.user.has_time_bonus?
    end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :order_template

    def has_time_bonus?
        p self.order_template.upgrade
        ------------------------> is false but i am expecting true
    end

end
```

Please smack me.

Comment: why don't you use attr_accessor if you want to read and write to :upgrade anyway?  . Writing a separate reader doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Well, i was playing with this too, changing to attr_accessor doesnt help me and to answer your question: i wrote it separately because i needed default value.

Comment: To get a false value you dont need to write a getter method ecause if you dont write anything to upgrade then it will eventually return false because in ruby nil and false evaluate to false .

Comment: And where in the code are you setting upgrade to true? Did you try creating an instance of OrderTemplate ? something like ot = OrderTemplate.new and then tried assigning ot.upgrade = true and then check if user models gets it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is "activerecord doesn't have an identity map" (or at least, it's not enabled). If you do

```
an_order_template.user.order_template
```

then `user.order_template` causes the `OrderTemplate` to be loaded from the database a second time, so you have two distinct in memory objects representing the same database row. The second copy won't have any in memory only changes (including your instance variable).

You can probably work around this by doing

```
class OrderTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :order_template
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :order_template, :inverse_of => :user
end
```

the `:inverse_of` option helps Active Record join the dots so that when you do

```
an_order_template.user.order_template
```

rails knows that two order templates are the same object.

Comment: You are 100% correct and your "workaround" works well. I read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations :-) immediately and i fill up my gap. Should we call it "workaround" as is written in there ? :-)